# Can Reducer read the same order af mapper output instead of group unique keys with values?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a basic understanding of how Hadoop order the data from Mapper to Reducer.
I have the following data written to `context` Mapper. The below data is a key, value pair

```
abc 1234
cde 2394
dec 8273
abc 2348
cde 8780
dec 6590
```

Key's `abc, cde, dec` continuous for n-times with same or different values.
Reducer reads in key with group of values. I.e

```
abc {1234, 2348, ...} and so on with other keys.
```

Question: Is there a possibility of reading data into reducer in a same order of Mapper output, instead of unique keys group with values ?

Comment: Are you using combiner in the middle? You won't get abc(1234,2348) without combiner in place.

Comment: What is your requirement?... If need the same order you can skip using reducer and just have the mapper in place

Comment: @madhu, you are right. But, my file contains some header in the beginning, which would be processed by a mapper. Data thereafter is related to the header. I need to process data based on header.

Comment: After reading the header, why can't you use Partitioner, Combiner & Sorter? Sorting the values before Reducer receiving the inputs is more efficient than sorting at Reducer

Answer (score 0):

If you are required to process the data based on header then i think you can use the below approach:-

`Mapper` :-

Cut the header and make that as your key and the remaining data as your value.
Now all of the data for that particular header will move to the reducer.

`Reducer` :-

We will be having these values in reducer without grouping.

```
abc 1234
cde 2394
dec 8273
abc 2348
cde 8780
dec 6590
```

Then we will be able to process the data individually.